# trigger click event with css selector in prototype

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, prototypejs

I am new in Prototype js. I have an element like this,

```
<li id="toolbar-save" class="button">
  <a class="toolbar"  href="www.mydomain.com/register">
     Save &amp; Close
  </a>
</li>
```

I have a selector for the anchor tag, `$$('#toolbar-save a')`.
By using this selector how can I trigger the **click** event ?
or any other way you can suggest ?
thanks in advance.

Comment: @pXL that's not working  getting error $$(...).click is not a function

Comment: Are you trying to do this with Prototype or jQuery? (Why the 'jquery' tag?)

Comment: @nnnnnn how can I write the prototype selector ?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
$$('#toolbar-save a')[0].click();
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/VUNSg/2/)

Comment: Edited the answer, and added a fiddle. Using $$ to select elements returns an array, so you either have to select the first element in the collection (or whichever you'd like) or iterate.

Comment: fire and simulate is getting the same error, working fine with $$('#toolbar-save a')[0].click()

Comment: @Nisam - you're right, I stopped testing when I got the selector right, but was sure `simulate()` would work, but it did'nt. `click()` does however work when you get the right element.

Comment: If you need get element by id method $('toolbar-save a') return one object in prototype by id without #

Method $$('#toolbar-save a') get array of elements with selector $$('#toolbar-save a')[0] retrieve first element in array, this way mostly use when need get elements by class or tagname